# CKEditor and ExpressJS - NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, ckeditor

ok so I'm using the CKEditor plugin. The problem I'm having is that I cannot add images or links. Whenever I try to add them it seems as if the textboxes where you put the URL in are disabled. I'm using ExpressJS and I downloaded the plugin from the official website: http://ckeditor.com/download. Everything else seems to be working except for these little problems.

Has this happened to anyone else and how can I fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really know why this happens but I managed to find the answer in the official forum.

http://ckeditor.com/forums/Support/Issue-with-Twitter-Bootstrap